# Where Are My Google Apps Domains?

Tags: google-apps-script

We've been using Google Apps for Edu in our University for some time now and we have multiple domain setups. There's a primary domain (uniben.edu e.g john.smith@uniben.edu) and other domains for students (scott.tigger@law.uniben.edu, john.smith@agric.uniben.edu). However, when I try to obtain all users using UserManager.getAllUsers(); it only returns accounts under the primary uniben.edu domain, leaving out accounts created / managed under the other domains.

Using Google App Script, how can I retrieve these other domains and get their users as well. I want to be able to inspect accounts across all our domains. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to access users from another domain. I'm not certain if it would work, but you could potentially create a script in each domain that returned the users for that domain, and then include those scripts as a library in the master script.

Comment: I created an account from one of the subdomains (user@agric.uniben.edu) and granted the user admin privilege. After logging in as the user, I created a script with a function that returns the result from a call to UserManager.getAllUSer(), with the hope that it will return users under the subdomain (@agric.uniben.edu). I then saved a  version and used it as a library from the main project. However, using it from the main project does not return users from the subdomain, even though tests from the script within the subdomain itself returns the right users.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the main project runs under the identity of a user that doesn't have access to that sub-domain. One possible solution is to set up a time-based trigger on the sub-domain script that reads the users and saves them to ScriptDB. Then provide a function in the library that reads the latest set of users from ScriptDB.

Comment: The main script runs with an account having super-admin role, which the subdomain is under, however I set up the time-based trigger and occasionally get "execution time exceeded" errors. Also, when I use the sub-domain script from the main script (as a library) I still get funny results. E.g calling getDomain() on the lib's UserManager object from the main script should return the sub domain name, but it returns the main domain name instead ??

Comment: See my comment above on Aug 15 regarding the library issue.